# I think "different" in here is not native

Tags: word-choice

A [multiple choice question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaYKV.jpg) has a blank to fill in.

> In different countries, people eat _______ food.

The options are

- A: different
- B: the same
- C: the different
- D: same

I think "various" is better than "different". How do you think about it?

Comment: That is a rubbish test book. Fish and chips **is** very popular in England, the rest of Britain, Canada and Australia. And probably the USA as well. It's a dish, singular. However, 'different' is not wrong there.

Comment: If you mean that you think that "different" is not how a native speaker would say it, then you are wrong. In many contexts, "various" can replace "different", but it cannot here, because "different" has an "each" interpretation (many singular items) while "various" lacks that.

Comment: Please don't post examples as images.

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you could explain *why* you think "different" is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *any given* country, people eat ***various*** food(s). The phrase in the question is getting at the idea that diets vary between countries. It's true to say that "in different countries, people eat various foods", and one might even be forgiven for making *food* singular instead, but in the context of the other questions they are clearly talking about the variation of food between countries.

***Different*** suggests that there is a particular habit of eating distinct to each country; *various* just suggests that, for each of several countries, there's an assortment of foods eaten. This is true, but not what the questions are getting at. In any case, you wouldn't tend to use various with the singular, even with a noun that can be a mass noun.

Not only that, but this is a multiple choice question; the answer has to be one of them. To suggest you should use *various* rather than *different* would be to assert that different shouldn't be used at all. It is a perfectly reasonable word to use here. If you think it isn't, you're going to have to explain why, or we aren't going to help you understand.